# Explode doesn't work with a string coming from JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

Javascript

```
<script>
    // when button clicked
    let tags = 'foo,bar';
    elem.innerHTML += `<x-post tags="${tags}"></x-post>`
</script>
```

post.blade.php

```php
@php
    var_dump($tags); // string(9) "foo,bar"
    $tags = explode(',',$tags); // exploding
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($tags); // array(1) { [0] => string(9) "foo,bar"} 
@endphp
```

How can I fix it? And why this is working correctly when I write `tags="foo,bar"`?

Expecting: array with foo and bar.

Tryed: `JSON.stringify()`, array, array with `JSON.stringify()`.

Actually, I'm sending a post with tags via ajax so that they load after clicking on the button, like pagination. It works without tags, but such a problem has arisen with them.

Maybe you know how i can normally send an array to a blade component like in php?

[image]

Comment: This is confusing to me. `elem.innerHTML += \`<x-post tags="${tags}"></x-post>\``  looks like an attempt to put a blade component in the document using JavaScript, something that I would not expect to work but your screenshot shows it as at least partially working.

Comment: @apokryfos
This works completely, except when something complicated is transmitted.

I don't understand why you are confused by this, because otherwise you would have to duplicate html in JS code, isn't that so?

I would be glad if you could show me how to get out of this situation differently. Any ajax loading of posts will suit me.

Comment: I'm confused because blade templates are rendered serverside by the blade compiler. JavaScript code runs clientside after the PHP code finishes executing. You understand my confusion? It is because at the point the JavaScript code is ran, the blade compiler has finished running and will not compile anything else, unless you're using any additional framework that can take care of this

Comment: @apokryfos Now i'm confused too. Why then var_dump is working? However, thank you. There were loops in my component and because blade turns into html before js, my approach would still not have given the correct result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be solved by creating an additional component.
After all, the problem is that I tried to process the string in php

```
let html = '';
html += `<x-post title=${post.title}>${post.content}`;
tags.forEach(function(tag){
    html += `<x-tag>${tag.name}</x-tag>`;
})
html += `</x-post>`;
elem.innerHTML += html;
```

Answer (score -2):

You're sending `tags` in string literal with double quotes i.e. `<x-post tags="${tags}"></x-post>` and therefore it's returning the total length of `$tags` 9.

Try without double quotes,

```
<script>
//in JS
let tags = 'foo,bar';
elem.innerHTML += `<x-post tags=${tags}></x-post>`
</script>

// post.blade.php
@php
    var_dump($tags); // string(7) "foo,bar"
    $tags = explode(',',$tags); // exploding
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($tags); // array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "foo" [1]=> string(3) "bar" } 
@endphp
```

Hope it wll help :)

Comment: still not working :( . I think it's impossible to fix it

Comment: What you are getting now?

Comment: same result.           /  some symbols for validation stackoverflow

Comment: How it could help tho?